# How to handle coordinates of map in different display sizes

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs: #wrapper and #map-frame.

The #wrapper has overflow:hidden and size of the window, while #map-frame is %150 size, to give the feeling of zooming into the map.

This map is an image with buildings and houses: I've made an array that has objects with different coordinates.

These coordinates are stored in nested arrays:
    [ [0,0],[10,10] ]
So an imaginary box from point x0y0 to x10y10

If when we click, our mouse coordinates are inside of this imaginary box, a function will be run - and it does.. until..
We resize the screen.

The image becomes smaller, so something that would've been at [[329, 461],[684,641]] is now unreachable in an image that on gets to 300...

Here is the code:

```
     var user = {
        gold: 20
     }
 var goTo= function(e){

    var frame = document.getElementById("map-frame");

    var x = e.offsetX; 
    var y = e.offsetY; 


    for(i = 0; i < spots.length; i++){//check for every spot in the map if we are inside the box
        var currentSpot = spots[i];
        if (    (x > currentSpot.coords[0][0] &&  y > currentSpot.coords[0][1]) && (x < currentSpot.coords[1][0] &&  y < currentSpot.coords[1][1])    ){
            console.log("Welcome to the " + currentSpot.name);
            currentSpot.action()
        }

    }

    frame.style.transform = "translate(-"+x/2+"px,-"+y/2+"px)";//this will center the camera at the point. kind of
}

var spots = [
    {
        coords: [[30,28],[135,87]],
        name: "Farm",
        action: function(){
            console.log("You enter the farm and are sold some hay")
        }
    },
    {
        coords: [[329, 461],[684,641]],
        name: "Fish Market",
        action: function(){
            if(user.gold > 10){
                console.log("You buy some fish and lose 10 gold")
                user.gold-=10;
            }
            else {
                console.log("You have no gold to buy fish!")
            }
        }
    }
];
```

And here is the HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Map Navigation</title>
<style>
    #wrapper {
        width:100vw;
        height: 100vh;overflow:hidden;position:relative;
       background-image:url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/XqRBXyO.jpg")
    }
 #map-frame{
    background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/xlolj0bg057z.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width:150%;
    height: 150%;
    transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" ><div id="map-frame" onclick="goTo(event)"></div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment I will have to leave an answer. Have you ever looked at leaflet.js? It is a very simple to use javascript library built specificly for this purpose. We use it where I work and it works flawlessly. It however works on latitude and longitude points, so that may not work for you. You can however put jpg's in and work with those, but I have not done any work with that yet.

Another option is to keep track of a ratio to how zoomed in the map is. So, when you zoom in keep track of a ratio to adjust your movement of x and y, and then along with that keep track of where the center of the camera is from the origin to + or - extra from the translation for x and y to get correct movement.

Does this answer your question? It might help if you set the map to a specific height to start the ratio at 100% as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction to solving this frustrating issue, I’ll look into these!

Comment: Hope that helps. If it works then please mark this as the correct answer.